# Jetty 11 and commons-fileupload

Tags: java, jetty, apache-commons, apache-commons-fileupload

I am updating Jetty9 to Jetty11. I updated my package from javax.servlet to jakarta.servlet because servlet 5.0 is the prerequisite for Jetty11. but the problem is when I am using commons-fileupload`-1.4.jar as it is still using java.servlet package.

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)
```

The above method is expecting argument from java.servlet package.

Latest version for commons-fileupload - https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22commons-fileupload%22%20AND%20g%3A%22commons-fileupload%22

Do we have any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`commons-fileupload` is not required from Servlet 3.1 onwards.

In fact, using `commons-fileupload` in combination with the a container that supports Servlet spec 3.1 (or newer) is actually not recommended.

There hasn't even been a release of `commons-fileupload` since 2018, and no releases that support Servlet 3.1 or newer (the last release of `commons-fileupload` supports Servlet 2.4 and older)

Why?

The Multipart features are built into the Servlet spec since 3.1.

Every server that supports Servlet 3.1 supports multipart file upload now.

That includes Jetty 9.

Use [`HttpServletRequest.getPart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart-java.lang.String-) API in code.
You configure it via either the [`@MultipartConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) annotation and/or the `<multipart-config>` descriptor element in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets011.htm

See also past answers on these features.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/775715

Comment: There is a small problem with Servlet API - it doesn't support `@MultipartConfig` on filters.

Comment: You shouldn't be reading Request content from a Filter, as that screws up the endpoint (Servlet) handling of the body content. (this even applies to using things like `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()` from a `Filter` as it breaks the ability of the Servlet to read the request body content)

Comment: A `Filter`, however, can decide that the request is something it wants to handle (not the Servlet at the end of the Filter chain), in that case it uses the `RequestDispatcher.forward()` to call a specific Servlet that handles the content, bypassing the original Servlet entirely.

Comment: Filters are more flexible than Servlets, anyway I found a solution how to support `@MultipartConfig` with filters just by skipping processing of the request in filter and letting servlet do the job - the config is bit more cumbersome, yet it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Apache released the project commons-fileupload2-jakarta compatible with the new API.

As a reference please find here a commit with the new Apache Fileupload commons version 2 -> https://github.com/talenteca/olon-web-framework/commit/4e7a7de8059cf8250024957f7f42c7f619a69dfe

**IMPORTANT:** Please use the standard new Servlet API 5 upload interface as previously comment ... only use this low level commons library from Apache when you have non servlets cases or some programmatic dynamic configuration for the uploader (annotations are not good at all for using dynamic values and the usage of XML could not be a viable option) ... for as at Olon Web Framework we use a filter that tries to automate everything, including file upload support with dynamic configuration and the new Apache commons is just perfect for that.