# Cannot use javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest in commons-fileupload:1.5 after Spring Boot upgraded to 3.x

Tags: spring-boot, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm trying to upgrade Spring Boot from 2.7.X to 3.X, and I got a compilation error since commons-fileupload:1.5 was till using `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` for request parsing, but Spring Boot 3.x is using `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` in the new version of embeded tomcat, which cause the mismatch. The same issue reported: [commons-fileupload and jakarta.servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517385/commons-fileupload-and-jakarta-servlet), and Apache is planning to release commons-fileupload 2.0.

Does anyone know when commons-fileupload 2.0 will be available?

Comment: To avoid the x-y problem (https://xyproblem.info/), do you **really need** commons-fileupload? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820846/2886891

Comment: Hi Honza, the reason why we use commons-fileupload in spring boot is we want to implement the large file upload features and monitor the upload progress, but spring boot doesn't seem to support monitoring the upload progress when uploading a large file, so we choose to use commons-fileupload instead. Actually there is a new release version 1.5 on Feb 13, 2023, it is still active.

Comment: Cannot you live just with the new Java Servlet? See also the very detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/2886891

Comment: Do you mean that using the native APIs from the new Java Servlet to implement the large file upload features? If so, is there an example of uploading a large file and monitoring the upload progress?