# Validate File Upload Request BEFORE File is Uploaded to Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

We have a REST service with an endpoint that receives file upload requests. All requests use an authentication token with a 5 minute timeout.

The problem is that Jetty seems to load the entire file BEFORE calling any of our code. This means that we cannot check the authentication token until after the full upload is finished, which causes large files to fail due to auth timeout.

Let's assume that increasing the Auth timeout is not an option. (Paperwork, red-tape, customer sign off, etc).

### First Approach: JAX-RS with MultiPart Form Data

Initially we were using JAX-RS to upload the file like this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response fileUpload (MultipartFormDataInput input) {
    ...
}
```

Authentication was checked in a Filter:

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        <check token>
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

We've been testing this locally using CURL with a rate limit:
`curl -v --cookie $TOKEN -F "file=@BigFile.zip" http://localhost:8080/file --limit-rate 10k`

We have log messages in all of our code. The CURL command hangs for a while and none of our logs are printed until the very end, long after the token has expired.

We also tried a `ContainerRequestFilter` and got the exact same results. Even with the `PreMatching` annotation.

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@PreMatching
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        <check token>
    }
}
```

To clarify, this approach works fine in most cases. It only has this problem with large files or the rate limiting in CURL.

### Second Approach: Using a Servlet

*Edit, removed the Apache FileUpload library*

We've tried rewriting the endpoint to use a Servlet in hopes that it would allow us to receive the raw request before the file is buffered.

```
@WebServlet("file")
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        print("Upload started");

       print("Upload finished");
    }
}
```

However, We're still getting the same results. The log messages from the servlet do not print until after the CURL command is done uploading the file.

Both of these CURL commands have the same results. They hang for a while with no log messages, then both of the Servlet logs appear and the command exits.

```
curl -v --cookie $TOKEN -F "file=@BigFile.zip" http://localhost:8080/file --limit-rate 10k

curl -v --cookie $TOKEN -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" http://localhost:8080/file --limit-rate 10k --data-binary "@BigFile.zip"
```

The expectation is that the Servlet logs would appear as soon as the CURL command is started. This would allow us to verify the TOKEN first, then load the file.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using commons-fileupload, that likely means you are using `javax.servlet` (as that does not support `jakarta.servlet`) and Jetty 9 or Jetty 10.  Both of those are at End of Community Support. See https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/10485 - you should be using Jetty 12 at this point in time, along with a REST library version that support at least Jakarta EE10.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, Yes we are still using the legacy version. Upgrading to Jakarta is on our list.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer about Jetty behavior, but not your specific REST library.

Jetty is doing exactly what the REST library is telling it to do.

You have declared in your REST library ...

```java
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response fileUpload (MultipartFormDataInput input) {
```

That is telling Jetty to load the entire `multipart/form-data` request body into an object called `MultipartFormDataInput` and then once it's entirely sent, give that object to your endpoint.

The thing is, the REST library called the Servlet API to access that MultiPart information (eg: `HttpServletRequest.getParameter` or `HttpServletRequest.getPart/getParts`) and that caused the read of the entire multipart form based on the REST library configuration of the `javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement`.

As to why your REST authentication doesn't trigger, that's outside of what I can help with.

Finally, commons-fileupload should not be used in modern Servlet containers.

See past answers about that:

- [How can I upload files to a server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-can-i-upload-files-to-a-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)
- [Jetty 11 and commons-fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820707/jetty-11-and-commons-fileupload/68820846#68820846)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of MultiPartFormDataInput. While that explains why the first approach didn't work, I'm still not clear on why in the second approach the Servlet isn't getting the request until after the entire file is uploaded by CURL.

Comment: The second approach (commons-fileupload) is entirely invalid on Servlet Containers using Servlet 3.0 or newer (for Jetty that would be Jetty 8.0 or newer).  The commons-fileupload library is for Servlet 2.4 or older Servlet Containers.

Comment: I've completely removed commons-fileupload. The servlet is now empty except for the log messages. The behavior is still the same, no log messages until after the file is uploaded (presumably by Jetty in the background). Am I correct in my expectation that the Servlet will allow us to skip the file being buffered by Jetty prior to any of our code being called, or is that unavoidable?

Comment: If you are still using `MultipartFormDataInput` then it will process the entire `multipart/form-data` before sending it to your REST endpoint.  (Change it to `InputStream` and you'll see the behavior you are looking for)  But you shouldn't focus on that though, focus on your Authentication step, that needs to process the request, and possibly reject it, before it reaches the REST Endpoint that attempts to process the `MultipartFormDataInput` object.  If you allow the REST Endpoint to proceed, of course it will behave like it does.

Comment: You might also want to look into how your REST library would handle `Expect: 100-Continue` style of HTTP request, those will send the request headers, allow the server to process the request headers ONLY, and based on the response of those headers (eg: Authentication), then the request body is actually sent by the client.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that our Kong gateway service was actually the culprit. It was buffering the entire file prior to calling the REST endpoint.

There were messages in the Kong logs like this:

```
[warn] 87400#0: *2723 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /usr/local/kong/client_body_temp/0000000001
```

After adding this to our `custom-nginx.conf`, both of the approaches from the original question work correctly with no modifications.

```
proxy_request_buffering  off;
```