# Jersey servlet version issues [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError] jakarta httpservlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I'm learning Java web technologies and I'm trying to deploy a trivial REST service using Jersey, when I try to access the resource I get greeted with the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/mkstick] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.setStatus(int, java.lang.String)'] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.setStatus(int, java.lang.String)'
```

My java class resource:

```
package com.dbmw.mkstick;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Resource {
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getText() {
         return "<html><head/><body>Hello world!</body></html>" ;
    }

}
```

My web xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.dbmw.mkstick</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dbmw</groupId>
    <artifactId>mkstick</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>mkstick</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>mkstick</finalName>
    </build>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

From what I can grasp it seems to be an issue with versions and I've tried to get every dependency up to date but it has not helped at all.

Comment: [setStatus](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletresponse#setStatus-int-java.lang.String-) is removed in Servlet 6. Possibly you use too new Tomcat (Tomcat 10.1.), for which you would need Jersey 3.1.0 which is not out, yet.

Answer (score 5):

As comment said, if you are deploying on Tomcat 10.1.x or greater you need to upgrade your jersey version to 3.1+ (it is out now).
To get a starting template use the maven build archetype for Jersey 3.1.1 as seen [here.](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/download.html)

This is a confusing error too because the updates from Tomcat 10.0.x to Tomcat 10.1.x entail an entire version jump in Servlet spec (version 5 to 6) [see link](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). Usually there arent such big version changes within the same major version ie 10.x